# Using "this" combined with other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, element, this

I use PHP and jQuery. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
$(this + ' .my_child_class').html('test');
```

I have a dynamic list of elements and when click on a button I use "this" to get to the current element group.

**The problem** is that I want to get to the class "my_child_class" which is somewhere within the current element group. The jQuery above don't work.

**The HTML could look like this:**

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="my_child_class">Content</div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" />
</div>

<div class="item">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="my_child_class">Content</div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put this code in your function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("div.item > input").bind('click',function() {

    $(this).prev().find('.my_child_class').html('test');

  });

});
```

You can find the whole solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/PLm5a/1/

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is happening in an event handler -- `this` is a DOM element there, not a string. You probably want this:

```
$(this).find('.my_child_class').html('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after? Something like:

```
$(this).closest(".item").find(".my_child_class").html("test");
```

attached to the input button.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `this` actually refers to, I suspect you need

```
$(this).find(".my_child_class").html("test");
```

You may want to take a look at the other [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) functions, too, depending on your situation.